# How to convert "0 days 00:09:06.633000000" object to minutes/hours/seconds?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I was working with some data in pandas as after saving it to `csv` it changed the format from `00:31:24.904000` `timedelta64[ns]` to `0 days 00:31:24.904000` `Object`.

```
0       0 days 00:25:20.835688000
1       0 days 00:01:44.004000000
2       0 days 00:18:29.023000000
3       0 days 00:09:06.633000000
4       0 days 00:02:16.826000000
                  ...            
6004    0 days 00:00:00.000000000
6005    0 days 00:31:24.904000000
6006    0 days 00:02:31.637000000
6007    0 days 00:03:40.214000000
6008    0 days 00:01:26.577000000
Name: Time, Length: 6009, dtype: object
```

How can I convert it back to timedelta or some other date/time related format?
How can I avoid such conversion during saving to csv

Comment: `pd.to_timedelta()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I convert it back to timedelta or some other date/time related format?

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
```

> How can I avoid such conversion during saving to csv

It is not possible, because in csv all data are strings.