# how to convert data which is in time delta into datetime.?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

```
|Event Date|startTime|
|----------|---------|
|2022-11-23|0 days 08:30:00|
```

when i was tring to get data a sql table to dataframe using variables from columns of other dataframe
it came like this i want it only the time `08:30:00` what to do to get the required output

output I need is like this

```
|Event Date|startTime|
|----------|---------|
|2022-11-23|08:30:00|
```

i tried

```
sql['startTime']=pd.to_datetime(df1['startTime']).dt.time
it is showing this error
TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
```

tried finding for it be didn't get anything useful solution but came across the opposite situation [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59170015/how-to-convert-0-days-000906-633000000-object-to-minutes-hours-seconds) still not useful info present in the question for my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the timedelta to a datetime, then you have a `time` component. Ex:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Event Date": ["2022-11-23"],
                   "startTime": ["0 days 08:30:00"]})

# ensure correct datatypes; that might be not necessary in your case
df["Event Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Event Date"])
df["startTime"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["startTime"])

# create a datetime Series that includes the timedelta
df["startDateTime"] = df["Event Date"] + df["startTime"]

df["startDateTime"].dt.time
0    08:30:00
Name: startDateTime, dtype: object
```